# Inserting "bad" data into a SQL database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a query that inserts customer data into a MSSQL database. Very basic.

Unfortunately, I ran into a problem when trying to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO USERS(newid(),'BOB''S SELECT MARKETING')
```

I made sure to escape my quotes, but the server is still seeing SELECT as a reserved keyword. I don't want to have to wrap a bunch of reserved words in brackets. Is there a cleaner way of getting my data in the database intact and not mangled by brackets?

I appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: That string looks very, very wrong.

Comment: @graysheep How are you executing that against your server? SSMS? A client application?  If it's a client application, can we see that code?  If you run this straight in SSMS, what happens?  There's nothing built into SQL Server that would prevent you from inserting a string that contains the word "SELECT", so something else is your issue...

Comment: @uvensten - That string is exactly right The '' in Bob''s  is the correct way to exape an apostrophe (single quote) for SQL Server.  I'm assuming this is SQL Server due to the tags. If it's another RDBMS then you may be on to something.

Comment: Why not use stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several choices of syntax here.  Using the one in your code sample, you forgot the VALUES keyword.  For example:

```
declare @users table
(
    id uniqueidentifier,
    name varchar(50)
)
insert into @users values (newid(), 'BOB''S SELECT MARKETING')
```

You can also use the insert into / select statement like below if you are inserting a value into each one of the table's columns:

```
declare @users table
(
    id uniqueidentifier,
    name varchar(50)
)
insert into @users 
select newid(), 'BOB''S SELECT MARKETING'
```

Or you can use the insert into / select statement and specify the columns you are inserting:

```
declare @users table
(
    id uniqueidentifier,
    name varchar(50)
)
insert into @users (id, name)
select newid(), 'BOB''S SELECT MARKETING'
```

Comment: You certainly **should** specify the column names, but it is not a prerequisite, and is not the reason the OP's insert was failing.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I was already in process of editing my response when you commented on it.  :)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the Key word `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (NEWID(),'BOB''S SELECT MARKETING');
```

Comment: Duh.  Why didn't I see that?  Good catch!  And also the space after Users - not sure if that matters, but yours is correct.